# Batch How can I rename a file saved into a variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-rename

this is my situation:

```
@echo off

Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set file=C:\Users\test\Desktop\fscls.cfg
```

how can I rename %file% variable to get (with an echo command):

```
C:\Users\test\Desktop\TIMESTAMP_fscls.cfg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%time%` environment variable contains a timestamp.

```
:: Remove colons from %time%
set ts=%time::=%

:: Remove centiseconds from %ts%
set ts=%ts:~0,-3%

:: file=HHMMSS_file
set file=%ts%_%file%
```

If you need your timestamp to include the date, you can get it by scraping the `%date%` environment variable in a similar manner.  See this page on [DOS String Manipulation](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) for more info.

If your `%file%` variable already has the path included and you're trying to insert the timestamp between the path and the filename, that's a little trickier.  You'll either need to use a `for /f` loop or to `call` a subroutine for batch parameter substitution.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set file=C:\Users\test\Desktop\fscls.cfg

:: set ds=YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.etc (the result of wmic os get localdatetime)
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime /format:list') do set ds=%%I

:: set ds=YYYYMMDD
set ds=%ds:~0,8%

:: Insert %ds% into %file%
call :insert "%file%" "%ds%_" file

echo new filename: %file%

:: end main
goto :EOF

:insert <path> <str_to_insert> <varname_to_set>
set "%~3=%~dp1%~2%~nx1"
```

See the last couple of pages of `help for` and `help call` for more info.

Comment: it seems to be a good solution, but I want to add a datestamp (YYYYMMDD), not a timestamp, sorry.

Comment: Indeed.  Well, as I mentioned between the example scripts in my answer, you can scrape the date from the `%date%` environment variable.  If you are concerned about system locale affecting the format of the `%date%` variable, you can get a system-agnostic date from `wmic os get localdatetime`.  You can capture the output of that `wmic` command using a `for /f` loop.  `for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime /format:list') do set datetime=%%I`; and then `%datetime:~0,8%` will give you your YYYYMMDD you're looking for.

Comment: @rschirin - OK, I modified the second script to get you the datestamp instead of the timestamp.  Enjoy.

Comment: hmmm...no, I don't understand.it's not possible to use the same code with %date% variable.

Comment: Of course not the same code.  You have to scrape and strip different bits of `%date%`.  Please see the [DOS String Manipulation](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) page to learn how to, for example, obtain the last four characters of a value; or substitute slashes with dashes, or remove the slashes altogether.

Comment: it seems don't work, because if I try to rename the original file with datestamp+filename I get as respons: the sintax of the command is incorrect. 
I call insert function with "%file%" "%data%_" file2
After that I call a rename %file% %file2%

Comment: Try enclosing the filenames within `ren "%file%" "%file2%"` within quotation marks.  If there's a space in the path, the `ren` (or `rename`) command needs the filenames to be quoted.